# Prevent disabling of google map and only disabling the droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps-api-3

I am working on GPS based product and what I exactly want to do is :

1) Drag a item on the div(droppable)

2) On drop action I'll display a map in the same div and mark information accordingly.

3) The dropable functionality should be switched off for that particular div.

Problem:
All is working fine except the disabling of droppable functionality.
I tried to disable the droppable, but it is actually disabling the div container due to which the MAP is being grayed out, which is not acceptable at all.

Please Help.. :(
Here is My Code:

**HTML:**

```
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="width: 30%; float: left; height: 500px;">
                <span id="bjcb" class="draggable" style="color:Red">What up</span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 70%; float: left; height: 500px;">
                <div style="width: 49.5%; height: 50%; float: left;" class="droppable" id="one"></div>
                <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: right;" class="droppable" id="two"></div>
                <div style="width: 49.5%; height: 50%; float: left;" class="droppable" id="three"></div>
                <div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: right;" class="droppable" id="four"></div>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({      
        revert: true
    });
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert('dropped');
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            $(this).html(ui.draggable.prop('id'));

            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var id = $(this).prop('id');

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), mapOptions);
            $(this).droppable("option", "disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
    .droppable
    {
        background-color: Gray;
        border: solid 1px Red;
    }
    .draggable
    {
        background-color: Transparent;
    }
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/writetobhuwan/LujAv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disabling the drop functionality. Try the following:

```
$(this).droppable("option", "disabled", true);
$(this).removeClass('ui-droppable ui-state-highlight ui-droppable-disabled ui-state-disabled');
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LujAv/8/